# How to mount data with Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I'm brand new to Azure Databricks, and my mentor suggested I complete the Machine Learning Bootcamp at

https://aischool.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning/learning-paths/ai-platform-engineering-bootcamps/custom-machine-learning-bootcamp

Unfortunately, after successfully setting up Azure Databricks, I've run into some issues in step 2.  I successfully added the 1_01_introduction file to my workspace as a notebook.  However, while the tutorial talks about teaching how to mount data in Azure Blob Storage, it seems to skip that step, which causes all of the next tutorial coding steps to throw errors.  The first code bit (which the tutorial tells me to run), and the error that comes up afterwards, are included below.

%run "../presenter/includes/mnt_blob"

Notebook not found: presenter/includes/mnt_blob. Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.

Stacktrace:
  /1_01_introduction: python

As far as I can tell, the Azure Blob storage just isn't set up yet, and so the code I run (as well as the code in all of the following steps) can't find the tutorial items that are supposed to be stored in the blob.  Any help you fine folks can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Setting up and mounting Blob Storage in Azure Databricks does take a few steps.

First, [create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-quickstart-create-account?tabs=azure-portal) and then [create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal#create-a-container) inside of it.

Next, keep a note of the following items:

- Storage account name: The name of the storage account when you created it
- Storage account key: This can be found in the Azure Portal on the resource page.
- Container name: The name of the container

In an Azure Databricks notebook, create variables for the above items.

```
storage_account_name = "Storage account name"
storage_account_key = "Storage account key"
container = "Container name"
```

Then, use the below code to set a Spark config to point to your instance of Azure Blob Storage.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.{0}.blob.core.windows.net".format(storage_account_name), storage_account_key)
```

To mount it to Azure Databricks, use the `dbutils.fs.mount` method. The source is the address to your instance of Azure Blob Storage and a specific container. The mount point is where it will be mounted in the Databricks File Storage on Azure Databricks. The extra configs is where you pass in the Spark config so it doesn't always need to be set.

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
 source = "wasbs://{0}@{1}.blob.core.windows.net".format(container, storage_account_name),
 mount_point = "/mnt/<Mount name>",
 extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.{0}.blob.core.windows.net".format(storage_account_name): storage_account_key}
)
```

With those set, you can now start using the mount. To check it can see files in the storage account, use the `dbutils.fs.ls` command.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/<Mount name>")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Jon.  I'll use this as a guide to get set up.  Still not sure what happened with the tutorial, but this should work just as well, if not better.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all data that we write to `dbfs:/mnt/<Mount name>` should be automatically uploaded to the container of the blob storage?

Comment: @Fluxy: indeed, if you write to the mount point, it will write into the blob container.

Comment: What is the point of the `spark.conf.set()` command?