# How to loop through folders in Azure Blob Containers

Tags: python, azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I have the following code which is written in Visual Studio Code. Now I want to run this in Azure Databricks. I have uploaded the entire folder to my Azure Blob Storage. I have named my container `Invoices`. Now I want to loop through all folders in my blob storage and carry on with my pdf processing steps.

```
root_path = 'B:\\Invoces\\' 
folders = ['202101','202102','202103','202104','202105','202106','202107','202108','202109','202110','202111','202112']
    files = []
    for folder in folders:
        dir_path = os.path.join(root_path,folder)
        ext = "*.pdf"
        PATH = "."
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
            files += glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, ext))
```

I am not sure how I can do this from Azure's point of view. What is the equivalent code I can develop and run in Azure Data Bricks to achieve the same result? I want to concatenate the folders with the `root_path` and get all pdf files.

Comment: Have you mounted the container to your dbfs? If so, then you'd just use `dbutils.fs.ls('/path/to/mount')` and iterate through the returned list

Comment: @C.Nivs what do you mean by dbfs? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777199/7867968) might be what you're looking for. [Here are the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-to-dbfs)